How do I flip a juicy pixel image saved from glut
I'm trying to make snapshots of a opengl area in a haskell program using the glut library.
I found this snippet of code using the juicypixels library.
saveImage :: Window -> IO ()
saveImage window = do
  currentWindow $= Just window
  Size w h <- get windowSize
  let npixels = fromIntegral (w*h) :: Int
      nbytes  = 3*npixels
  fptr <- mallocForeignPtrArray nbytes :: IO (ForeignPtr Word8)
  withForeignPtr fptr $ \ptr -> do
    let pdata = PixelData RGB UnsignedByte ptr :: PixelData Word8
    readPixels (Position 0 0) (Size w h) pdata
  let fptr' = castForeignPtr fptr :: ForeignPtr (PixelBaseComponent PixelRGB8)
  let imgdata = unsafeFromForeignPtr0 fptr' npixels :: Vector (PixelBaseComponent PixelRGB8)
  let image = Image (fromIntegral w) (fromIntegral h) imgdata :: Image PixelRGB8
  writePng "test.png" image

This code is running well. Just a problem, it save the png image like this :

The image is flipped vertically
So, I tried to flip my image to get it in the right direction.
I found this function flipVertically and implemented it locally:
flipVertically :: Image PixelRGB8 -> Image PixelRGB8
flipVertically img@Image {..} =
  generateImage gen imageWidth imageHeight
  where
    gen x y = pixelAt img x (imageHeight - 1 - y)

When I use it
writePng "test.png" (flipVertically image)

My program fail with the following error message
geometrix-cli_gl_snap: ./Data/Vector/Generic.hs:257 ((!)): index out of bounds (1079997,360000)
CallStack (from HasCallStack):
  error, called at ./Data/Vector/Internal/Check.hs:87:5 in vector-0.12.3.1-TXkE6leK98EdYcmdk29JF:Data.Vector.Internal.Check

It seems that it's trying to access an index (1079997) out of my image (600*600=360000px).
as a juicypixels image is made with a vector, I tried to convert the vector to a list, reverse this list and reconvert it to a vector with the functions toList and fromList.
  let lst = (V.toList imgdata)
  let image = Image (fromIntegral w) (fromIntegral h) (V.fromList (reverse (lst))) :: Image PixelRGB8

the program is running but instead of my image in the right direction, I have this free style:

The top of the image seems to be correctly flipped, but the bottom is a non sense.
When I test the list length, I get 360000. So it contain the right amount of pixels for my image.
What did I do wrong in my function ?
How do I flip a juicypixels image correctly ?

If the color-space is three bytes per color, that is not a problem. Since then 1079997/3/600 = 599.9983..., so the last row, and last column.

I think it is more that it is a mismatch in the "colorspace", so the image has different bounds than the data it represents.

Can you point where you found the first snippet?

https://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/dee0iz/converting_opengl_window_to_a_png_image_in_haskell/

In fact, it's not rotate180 but flipVertically I should use.

The culprit is where you convert the pointer into a Vector, you here make a Vector of essentially bytes with length npixels, whereas it should be nbytes, since PixelBaseComponent PixelRGB8 takes the byte size of one channel, indeed [Haskell-src]:
instance Pixel PixelRGB8 where
  type PixelBaseComponent PixelRGB8 = Word8
  -- …
It is possible that if you save an image, and it uses a pointer, that might still work, but the vector is here to essentially make sure you can not access data outside the bounds.
You thus should use:
saveImage :: Window -> IO ()
saveImage window = do
  currentWindow $= Just window
  Size w h <- get windowSize
  let npixels = fromIntegral (w * h) :: Int
      nbytes = 3 * npixels
  fptr <- mallocForeignPtrArray nbytes :: IO (ForeignPtr Word8)
  withForeignPtr fptr $ \ptr -> do
    let pdata = PixelData RGB UnsignedByte ptr :: PixelData Word8
    readPixels (Position 0 0) (Size w h) pdata
  let fptr' = castForeignPtr fptr :: ForeignPtr (PixelBaseComponent PixelRGB8)
  let imgdata = unsafeFromForeignPtr0 fptr' nbytes :: Vector (PixelBaseComponent PixelRGB8)
  let image = Image (fromIntegral w) (fromIntegral h) imgdata :: Image PixelRGB8
  writePng "test.png" (rotate180 image)
